# Supplying type annotation to a generic trait function

Tags: rust

Consider the following (hacky) implementation of an interpreter:

```
trait Visitor<T> {
    fn visit(&mut self, node: &Box<dyn ASTNode>) -> T;
}

pub struct Interpreter {
    parser: Parser,
    global_scope: HashMap<String, f64>,
}

impl Interpreter {
    // snip
    fn visit_assign_node(&mut self, node: &AssignNode) -> Result<(), String> {
        let var = node.get_left().get_token().get_identifier().clone();

        match self.visit(node.get_expr()) {
            Ok(val) => self.global_scope.insert(var, val),
            Err(e) => return Err(e),
        }
        Ok(())
    }
    // snip
}

impl Visitor<Result<f64, String>> for Interpreter {
    fn visit(&mut self, node: &Box<dyn ASTNode>) -> Result<f64, String> {
        // snip
    }
}

impl Visitor<Result<(), String>> for Interpreter {
    fn visit(&mut self, node: &Box<dyn ASTNode>) -> Result<(), String> {
        // snip
    }
}
```

Above code won't compile, complaining that type annotations are needed for the match statement.
It compiles if I change the following:

```
let result: Result<f64, String> = self.visit(node.get_expr());
match result {
    // snip
}
```

That looks verbose and unclean, though. Using `self.visit::<Result<f64, String>>()` does not work, though: Rust expects 0 type parameters, receives one.

Does anyone know if there's a more idiomatic way to solve my problem?

Comment: tl;dr `Visitor::<Result<f64, String>>::visit(&mut self, node.get_expr())` or `match (self.visit(node.get_expr()): Result<f64, String>)` with the nightly [type ascription](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0803-type-ascription.md).

Comment: thank you, that's perfect! Put that in an answer and I'll accept (that is, if you don't consider my question to be a duplicate.)

Comment: BTW, `&Box<dyn AstNode>` is redundant. It can be `&dyn AstNode` instead.

Comment: @Lambda fairy Thank you! Any corrections of my style are always welcome.